# highchart polar chart with length and angle series instead of pointInterval

Tags: highcharts

Currently polar chart in highchart is placing the points in fix interval set by pointInterval. Is it possible to enter coordinates in series by length and angle (or x and y)?
i.e. instead of having:

```
series: [
    {
       type: "line",
       data: [1,5,3,2,1],
       pointInterval: 45,
     }
   ],
```

I'd like to have:

```
series: [
        {
          type: "line",
          data: [[0,1],[40,5],[60,3],[150,2],[220,1]]
        }
      ],
```

Where the first item is the angle and the second item is length.

Comment: Please provide a little more information about the issue. Do you want to plot the points at 0, 40, 60, 150 and 220 degrees?

Comment: yes, that's what I'm trying to do. It can be done by x and y coordinate (setting polar=false) and using r*sin(angle), r*cos(angle). but I'm wondering if there is a way to achieve this with polar = true.

Comment: Hi @Reza, Could you create some live example with the solution with disabled `polar` option? You can start from: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9gb6t08k/

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek. Actually just enabling the polar to true in the example you provided is doing what I was looking for. Thanks for your help.